# Maximo Linear: Define work order start/end measures by clicking map?

Tags: configuration, customization, maximo, data-entry

I have the **Linear** add-on in **Maximo**.

The Linear add-on allows me to define work orders on **portions** of linear assets. (*This technique is known as linear referencing.*)

Example:

- A road is 300m long.
- I can define a work order from 150m to 200m along the road.

---

I am able to define the `Start Measure` and `End Measure` in the work order by manually typing numbers into the fields:

[image]

However, it would be more practical if I could define the `Start Measure` and `End Measure` by **clicking** the start point and end point on the line **in the map** (instead of entering/guessing manually).

**How can I define WO start/end measures by clicking on the map?**

*(Version 7.6.1.1; Maximo Linear;  Maximo Spatial 7.6.0.5)*

Answer (score 2):

Spatial is intended as a framework for customization.  You would need to build a widget that understands the relationship between the geometry layer and the linear value set up in maximo.  Hopefully this data would be synced so it would match fairly exactly, Maximo linear length = shape.length in GIS. After that you have to set up snapping to the line and evaluate the chosen point against length.  We had issues with lines drawn the wrong direction when building this for a dataset and had to do a big data clean before deploying.

Answer (score 1):

Linear and Spatial are completely independent products with some "functional space" overlap. They overlap because they both have coordinates, but they are otherwise quite different in where data gets stored, which system does what work, and what system of reference is used. If both are used, I expect there would be a lot of data inside Maximo in Linear that was a duplicate of what was outside Maximo in the Spatial service provider (usually ArcGIS).

To solve your problem, you would need to define some line-type feature class in Spatial and configure it for use by work orders. Then, for work orders of that feature class, you could have an automation script (invoked from a button?) to translate that Spatial-Line information into the Start Measure and End Measure data you want for your Linear. And that's assuming you can have the WO be flagged as both Spatial and Linear -- which I think you can do, but I could very well be wrong.

Comment: The latest version of Spatial has Linear built into it.  It uses the data similar to what people refer to the "Layer cake" on specifications.  It projects them one at a time onto a single asset on the map.  I would need to check, but I think this is possible for workorders that are not connected to a feature class, like preacher said.  One at a time is not super effective or efficient.